# How to push values to local storage?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, local-storage

I have the following code in js. if I use static array everything works fine. Else I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: myArray.push is not a function

```
function test(){
var myArray =  localStorage.getItem('articles')  ;
//myArray=[1,4,5];
needle = 2    ,
myArray.push(needle);
localStorage.setItem('articles', JSON.stringify(myArray))
console.log(localStorage.getItem('articles'));
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` will return `JSON string` instead of `JSON Object`. Hence, you should parse it before pushing into an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're stringifying it, you need to parse it out of the string format to use `push`:

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("articles"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add checking if 'articles' exists in localStorage and if it is an array.
If it doesn't exist yet. Initialized a value for it ("[]");
You need to parse the JSON string first before push an item to the array. Then stringify it again before you update the localStorage.
Please see the code below.

```
function test() {
  let myArray = localStorage.getItem("articles");
  //Check if localStorage has 'articles' and if that 'articles' is an array
  if (myArray && Array.isArray(JSON.parse(myArray))) {
    const needle = 2,
    myArray = JSON.parse(myArray).push(needle);
    localStorage.setItem("articles", JSON.stringify(myArray))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("articles"));
  } else {
    //Initialized 'articles' in localStorage.
    localStorage.setItem("articles", "[]");
  }
}
```